# Is there a Sesame SAIL for Jena TDB?

Tags: jena, sesame, tdb

Does anybody know of a Sesame SAIL implementation for the Jena TDB triple store?  Even a beta version would be helpful to get started with.

[EDIT]
To satisfy whoever voted this question down for lack of research: I've queried the Jena archives, searched Stackoverflow, and googled a LOT, and did find only this: http://sjadapter.sourceforge.net/ but it's as old as dirt and does not seem like a reasonable starting point.

Comment: I didn't downvote, although the original version of the question didn't *demonstrate* the research you'd performed.  However, it's still probably off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's a tool/library request: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  In this case, I think that your best bet might be to ask on the Jena and Sesame mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [this](http://sjadapter.sourceforge.net/), which is almost as old as time, itself. That's probably as close to something as you'll find without implementing it yourself from scratch. Given how old it is, you'll probably still be implementing it from scratch, with this just serving as an example.

Comment: Yes, I did stumble across that -- and I agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SPARQL and run TDB with Fuseki, then access from Sesame over HTTP.